# As a ASP.NET programmer, do I need to be concerned about email injection attacks?

Tags: asp.net, security, email

There are lots of PHP articles about the subject so is this a PHP only problem.
I am sending emails using System.Net.Mail after some regular expression checks of course.
Similar to http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/10/432854.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the PHP email injection attack works because of a weakness in the PHP Mail() function. As a .net developer you need not worry.

Answer (score 4):

I've never heard of that issue in ASP.NET.  However, you should trust user input about as much as you'd trust a hooker with your wallet.

Answer (score 4):

As long as you are using the [MailAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress.aspx) object, I think you're fine, because injections will only manage to throw FormatExceptions for the specified address.

Examples of how to properly use the System.Net.Mail components are included in that MSDN page; be sure to follow them and you will be fine.